# Tips for building a site statistics backend?

Tags: visitor-statistic, web-statistics

I'd like to build site statistics that are a bit more substantial than just google analytics.
(lots more user specific logging, associated with their login, recording of ajax tasks)

Are relational databases ok?
From previous fiddlings I've found that databases seem to get pretty large pretty quick if trying to record lots of site statistics, but that may have been to my bad handling of the database..

Any languages/platforms that should be avoided?

Any good comprehensive site statistics software that should be looked at?
(Tried to look at Piwik, but their site seems to be down.)

Is this a bad idea? :)

Comment: Are you sure you can't do it with Google Analytics? Look into their documentation on custom variables and event tracking.

Comment: Well.. I think you need to go on this way -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable with your DB/File System.